# How to fix the peeling and cracking of leather?

Tags: recycling

The surface of my leather sofa has worn out and started peeling off and cracking.I have used dye and leather filler to fix the cracking but it cracked again after few month.  Is there any method which helps to transform it permanently and also work for peeling off?

Comment: You can’t fix either, but the treatment to prevent it getting worse depends on the type of leather- broadly aniline or split/painted will react very differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glycerine (sold in pharmacies) is used to soften stiff leather and prevent it from cracking. It won't fix the cracks that already exist but you could use it to prevent further deterioration.